# Python PySerial Reading Port Has Delay

Tags: python, c++, arduino, pyserial, arduino-uno

I am relatively new to arduino and pyserial and have followed several tutorials on how to read data from an arduino using python. The problem is, there is a significant delay on receiving and using the data.

ARDUINO SCRIPT:

```
const int SW_pin = 2;
const int X_pin = 0;
const int Y_pin = 1;

void setup(){
  pinMode(SW_pin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(SW_pin, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  int buttonread = digitalRead(SW_pin);
  int xread = analogRead(X_pin);
  int yread = analogRead(Y_pin);
  
  Serial.print(String(buttonread) + ":" + String(xread) + ":" + String(yread));
}
```

PYTHON SCRIPT:

```
import serial            #Install Modules
import pydirectinput as pg

pg.FAILSAFE=False


ser = serial.Serial("COM3",'9600')  #Enter Arduino Port Number
while True:  
    read = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    print(read)
```

I am not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Your Arduino code is flooding the serial buffer as soon as it begins. Depending on when you start the Python script you will be reading older data, as you will be emptying the backlog of data in the serial buffer. Is that the delay you are referring to?

Comment: I think it might, as I am not sure where the delay is coming from. However, the tutorial script did add a delay, which I removed due to the mouse movement being too choppy and slow.

Comment: You could try doing something like a `ser.read_all()` in Python to empty the buffer before your loop starts. You should also be careful that the buffer is not getting written to faster than you're reading it, otherwise you'll fill it up and add a delay again.

Comment: Oooooh, thank you, I will go ahead and try that.

Comment: Huh, that is weird. I have now run into a new problem, and that being that it doesn't even print anymore. Edit: Wait no, I have fixed it; the problem was that it was all in one line.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I have found the root cause of this issue and have discovered that it is not with pyserial, but rather with pyautogui. It turns out that pyautogui delays when moving the mouse, but it had been receiving the information just well.